# How can I find out which color is there on an image of map based on the coordinates of the location?

Tags: python-3.x, maps

I have this image of the map of India and I want to find out what is the color on the map if I search for a coordinate.

This is for a project I am trying to implement using Python.

For example, in this image if I search for 28.7041° N, 77.1025° E which is the coordinates for Delhi, India, I want to get that the color at that coordinates  is orange.
Link to image : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GDj_HCnAy_CgL9IQ0d2p8Q8Dd4i-eydK

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit vague question but I'll try to guide you showing you example code. **This is bogus code to help you find the right library and execution path, ultimately you will have to roll your own**

1 - Request for the coordinates in the web service you want to download image from. This will probably be easier using a web library such as `requests` or any other scraping library.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://my-web-service', params={'lat':42.42,'lng':77.1025})
```

2 - Locate the image url in the response, make another request to download the image. You may need to parse the response using `re` or using other forms of web parsing (such as `beautifulsoup`)

```
image_url = re.match('https://[a-z].png', resp.text).group(0)
image_resp = requests.get(image_url)
```

3 - Feed the content of the image to an image library such as `pyopencv`

```
import cv2

img_array = cv2.imdecode(image_resp.content)
```

4 - Check the pixel

```
print(img_array[40][40])
```